# За что отвечает параметр offset в функции get_inline_bot_results?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, pyrogram

Я решил написать своё пользовательское приложение для работы с телеграм-ботом (murglar_bot), который позволяет доставать музыкальный трек из разных сервисов просто по запросу (названию исполнителя и названию песни).

Привожу скриншот как это работает с точки зрения пользователя.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А теперь что я пытаюсь сделать в коде, чтобы повторить результат, но программно:

```
from pyrogram import Client, filters
import time


app = Client(
    "my_account",
    api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash,
)


async def main():
    async with app:
        bot_results = await app.get_inline_bot_results(
            "murglar_bot",
            query="@murglar_bot Индульгенция Против меня",
            offset="???"
        )

        for res in bot_results.results:
            print(res.id + " : " + res.title)


app.run(main())
```

Вывод приложения сильно отличается от вывода в клиенте телеграма:

```
sz_49146474_mp3_320 : Егор Крид, MOLLY - Если ты меня не любишь (E.M.O.…

sz_47459295_mp3_320 : Егор Крид, MOLLY - Если ты меня не любишь (Если…

sz_69372333_mp3_320 : MORGENSHTERN - Если я спал с тобой (ДО ТОГО КАК СТАЛ ИЗВЕСТЕН)

sz_44623524_mp3_320 : Дискотека Авария, Мумий Тролль - Дельфины (Дискотека…

sz_44623531_mp3_320 : Дискотека Авария, Мумий Тролль - Девочка (Дискотека…
```

Как можно заметить некоторые песни совпадают, некоторые отсутствуют. Да и количество результирующих элементов после запуска кода значительно меньше. Моё предположение заключается в том, что выдаются не все результаты и нужно делать повторный запрос, но с неким "сдвигом". За который возможно отвечает параметр **offset** в функции **get_inline_bot_results**.

Вопрос: так ли это? За что этот параметр в действительности отвечает? Какие значения он принимает?
Лично я перепробовал все целые числа: на вывод это никак не повлияло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в этой строчке кода:

```
    bot_results = await app.get_inline_bot_results(
        "murglar_bot",
        query="@murglar_bot Индульгенция Против меня"
    )
```

Я пытался имитировать действия пользователя, т.е. ручками написать в запросе (параметр **query**) *@murglar_bot  Индульгенция Против меня* - а нужно было просто передавать сразу сам запрос без прямого обращения к боту, т.е. вот так:

```
    bot_results = await app.get_inline_bot_results(
        "murglar_bot",
        query="Индульгенция Против меня"
    )
```

И никакой **offset** не нужен здесь:)